# How do I change the background color of a .gif in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to change the background of an image from white to grey in Adobe Photoshop, but I can't find out how to do it.

Can someone assist me ?

Comment: i'm using Adobe Photoshop CS3

Answer (score 3):

Open up the image in Photoshop and select the Magic Wand tool, or press 'w' for a short cut. You can then use this tool to select a specific area of one colour on the image you want to play around with. If you just want to fill it with a block colour then select the paint bucket tool, or press 'g' for a shortcut. Then click on the colour blocks at the bottom of the tool bar (window>tools if its not showing) and pick a colour from the screen there. Then click on the part of the image you want to change the colour of. Press ctrl+d to deselect the area and see your results. File>Save As to save your image afterwards.

See:

http://www.ehow.com/how_8104_add-background-color.html

A tutorial shwoing a way to cut round complex objects and fill.

http://silurus.acnatsci.org/ACSI/corresp/digital_imaging_tips2.html

Comment: Hi, thx for the quick and detailed respond!

Comment: HI, i am still having a bit of a prolbem. the bucket colors the whole picture. i am trying to change the backround of ajaxrating if you are familiar with

Answer (score 0):

As my way to do this (All by keyboard ;-) ):
(with this you will be also far from suddenly overwriting)

1) I open my gif file by Photoshop;
2) I Select all image by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
3) I create a new file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.
4) I paste it from clipboard by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, that it comes as a new Layer.
5) Now you have to layer, In the `Background Layer` do your edits like `fill by foreColor`.
6) I save my new file as GIF ...

I hope it helps ;-).